# Retrieving a Deeply Nested Value in an XML File

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to read a property in an XML file using C# and LINQ XML and I can't retrieve a value that is deeply nested in the tree. The value I'm trying to get is the contents of `<Value>` near `<DisplayName>Add Your Comments</DisplayName>`. Every `<OrderProduct id=???>` may have its own comments.

I can read other properties in the XML file using LINQ, but I'm confused how to go about reading something so deeply nested.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OrderXml>
  <Order>
    <OrderProducts>
      <OrderProduct id="1">
      .
      .
      .
      </OrderProduct>

      <OrderProduct id="2">
        <PropertyValues>
          <PropertyValue>
            <Property id="10786">
              <DisplayName>Base</DisplayName>
            </Property>
            <Value />
          </PropertyValue>

          <PropertyValue>
            <Property id="10846">
              <DisplayName>Add Your Comments</DisplayName>
            </Property>
            <Value>this is a comment</Value>
          </PropertyValue>
        </PropertyValues>
      </OrderProduct>
    </OrderProducts>
  </Order>
</OrderXml>
```

This is the code I have so far. I can retrieve the "Add Your Comments" part, but I'm stuck in how to get the  part that follows it.

```
string productOrderID = ""; 
string productName = "";

XElement xelement;
xelement = XElement.Load (@"D:\Order.xml");

IEnumerable<XElement> Products = xelement.Descendants ("OrderProduct");

foreach (var order in Products)
{
  productOrderID = order.Attribute ("id").Value;
  productName = order.Element ("Product").Element ("Name").Value;

  Console.WriteLine ("productOrderID: {0}", productOrderID);
  Console.WriteLine ("productName: {0}", productName);
  Console.WriteLine ("");

  IEnumerable<XElement> PropertyValues = xelement.Descendants ("PropertyValues").Elements ("PropertyValue");

  foreach (var propValue in PropertyValues.Elements ("Property").Elements ("DisplayName"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("Property ID: {0}", propValue.Value);

    if (propValue.Value == "Add Your Comments")
    {
      Console.WriteLine ("---");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "so deeply"? You can get all the nested XElements of any XContainer by calling Decendants() method and do what ever filtering on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants.aspx) to search for nodes in document no matter where they are:

```
string name = "Add Your Comments";
var value = xdoc
   .Descendants("PropertyValue")
   .Where(pv => (string)pv.Element("Property").Element("DisplayName") == name)
   .Select(pv => (string)pv.Element("Value"))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Output:

```
this is a comment
```

Comment: xdoc.Descendants("//PropertyValue") what does "//" do here?

Comment: @Alireza that already fixed - I tried xpath before, forgot to change

Comment: Ok, what is the Stackoverflow convention in situations like this? Should I delete my comment or not?

Comment: @Alireza it's completely up to you :) During first five minutes answers often got changed (due to typos, or wrong copy-paste) so, that's normal situation